# Changing cursor on a bokeh map

Tags: bokeh

I've made a map using Bokeh, like the first example on [this page](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html), except the user can zoom in/out by scrolling up/down, and can tap circles I've added to the map to select them.

At the moment when the cursor is over the map it's the `default` arrow. If I click and drag the map the cursor changes to the `text` cursor for some reason. It doesn't change with any other action.

I'd like to be able to change the [cursor appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) so that:

1. When over the map it's the `grab` cursor
2. When dragging the map it's the `grabbing` cursor
3. When over a circle it's the `pointer` cursor

I can achieve (1) with:

```css
.bk { cursor: grab; }
```

but I'm not sure how to achieve the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following suggestions from the other post I came with this: (works for Bokeh v1.3.0):

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure(tools='pan, tap, reset')
p.circle(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3], size=30)

code_pan_start = '''
    Bokeh.grabbing = true
    var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('bk-canvas-events')[0]
    elm.style.cursor = 'grabbing'  
'''

code_pan_end = '''
    if(Bokeh.grabbing) {
        Bokeh.grabbing = false
        var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('bk-canvas-events')[0]
        elm.style.cursor = 'grab'        
    }
'''

code_hover = '''
if((Bokeh.grabbing == 'undefined') || !Bokeh.grabbing) {
    var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('bk-canvas-events')[0]
    if (cb_data.index.indices.length > 0)
        elm.style.cursor = 'pointer' 
    else
        elm.style.cursor = 'grab'
}
'''

p.js_on_event('panstart', CustomJS(code = code_pan_start))
p.js_on_event('panend', CustomJS(code = code_pan_end))

p.add_tools(HoverTool(callback = CustomJS(code = code_hover)))

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have a Bokeh thing to try this on now – had to change to an alternative due to our requirements – but this looks good. Thanks for the animation too!

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use the [`PanStart`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/events.html#bokeh.events.PanStart) and [`PanEnd`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/events.html#bokeh.events.PanStart) events to set/reset the cursor on drag operations. I think the hover will be difficult to achieve. Currently there is a `callback` property on hover tools that can be used trigger JS code when an inspection happens on a point. But it only fires when there is an inspection, there is no corresponding event or hook for "un-inspection" so I am not sure how you would reliably clear the cursor state when the user is no longer hovering over the circle.

Comment: Thanks. That's a shame. It'd be nice to have an indication for cursor-using systems that the shapes are clickable.

Comment: There has not been any appreciable demand expressed for this, and core dev resources are stretched. Familiar OSS story. Still, you are welcome to open an issue to discuss ideas (especially if you have capability to help out) at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues Also, an "accept" on the answer would be appreciated (better for the project not to have lingering questions without accepted answers)